# Bazar Repository - Concept of branches and

Tags: version-control, bazaar

Hi all 
I am writing a repository adapter for Bzr. This is for a search engine where adapter lets me communicate to some bzr repo, check the connection, checkout or update the projects. (No commit, push or create repos)
Now i dont have much experience with Bzr and such details of other scms too and  get confused with its branches concept.
I use
--> bzr checkout branchlocation mylocallocation -- to checkout projects
and
--> bzr ls URlwithbranchname --to test repo.

1. Is there any tutorial on internet with basic beginners information? about branches and structure of bzr organization.
   I have gone through canaonical website already.
2. Any way to run checkout or list on repo name or project name, not on branch name?
3. For checkout/list, do i need to take care of username/pass authentication on repo too?
4. Also I am still not sure about bzr over ssh, sftp, ftp servers. Would it be extra functionality to allow checkout from these servers.
   like authentication? or any kind of handle. I know checkout works for plain http.

Any kind of basic documentation would be very helpful for me being naive to bzr.

Answer (score 1):

1. http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.dev/en/user-guide/core_concepts.html http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.dev/en/user-guide/bazaar_workflows.html
2. No there is no functionality to check out a repository. You can list all the branches under a repository or a normal directory with the `bzr branches` command from the bzr-tools plugin. I think you can view the combined log of all the branches in a repository using `bzr qlog` from the qbzr plugin.
3. I would think any access would require the same authentication. You can set up your local bazaar to [automatically authenticate](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/latest/en/user-reference/authentication-help.html).
4. [sftp, ftp and bzr+ssh are supported protocals](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/latest/en/admin-guide/other-setups.html) and do not need any extra setup. (Except for bzr+ssh you need bzr installed on the server)

Comment: Bzr branches came out to be very useful but very slow.A